# Value's from plist to tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, plist

I'm trying to use a plist to fill my tableView. I've currently written this code. I'm not having any errors and I can run the app fine. The problem is the tableview remains empty. My println returns all the value's from my plist tho. If I request them outside my viewDidLoad function nothing comes up tho. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Sorry for asking an almost similar question as my previous one. It's just that I'm trying to teach myself a new language.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var artists: Array<String> = []
var stages: Array<String> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TableRowInfo", ofType: "plist")!
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path)!

    artists = dict["Artist"] as Array<String>
    stages = dict["Stage"] as Array<String>
    println(artists)
    println(stages)
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return artists.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("InfoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "InfoCell")
        cell!.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = artists[indexPath.row]
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = stages[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set the delegate and data source? Reloaded the table?

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks forget the connections to the viewcontroller. So stupid. Working perfectly now thanks!